# Closing the Quick Action Modal Popup in Mobile App

Tags: modal, lightning-quickaction

I have created a Quick Action lightning Component. In Mobile App , there is no way to close the Modal Popup window. So i added a Cancel button. The button shows on Desktop but not in the Mobile App.

Am i missing something ?

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" type="button" label="Cancel" title="Cancel"  onclick="{!c.cancelAction}"/> 


cancelAction: function(component, event, helper) {
  $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<lightning:button variant="brand" type="button" label="Cancel" title="Cancel"  onclick="{!c.cancelAction}"/> 


cancelAction: function(component, event, helper) {
```

$A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();

This actually works. It took longer to show up on Mobile app, but showed instantaneously on Desktop.